KVM isn't availible in Android Studio
I am trying to make my CPU fan less loud while using Android Studio, and the main way I want to do that is making the emulator less resource-intensive. I have heared you can do that via KVM, so I tried setting that up. I am in the KVM group so I can run virtual machines without sudo, but in Android studio there are no options for KVM or hardware acceleration, and if I run the VM and check the cpuinfo on there it doesn't say it uses kvm (according to Gemini I can use adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E "vmx|svm" while the virtual phone is running to check but that returns nothing). Is there anything I might be doing wrong? (I use the Snap stable version if that's important)
This might be similar to Enabling KVM for Android Emulator but the only answer there didn't help me either
Thanks
